# hide custom setting menu in abp framework

Tags: webassembly, abp

I have a self-created menu item under Settings, which should only be displayed if the user has the permission for it.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RNq5.png)

In the SettingComponentContributor, I have the following code:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckPermissionsAsync(SettingComponentCreationContext context)
 {
            var auth = context.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();            
            return await auth.IsGrantedAsync(Permissions.CustomSettings);
 }
public Task ConfigureAsync(SettingComponentCreationContext context)
{
            var l = context.ServiceProvider.GetService<IStringLocalizer<...Resource>>();

            context.Groups.Add(new SettingComponentGroup("Settings", l["Settings"], typeof(CustomSettingComponent)));
            return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `CheckPermissionsAsync` method for permission check and then add your setting menu item:

So, you can update the `ConfigureAsync` method as follows:

```cs
public Task ConfigureAsync(SettingComponentCreationContext context)
{
    if (!await CheckPermissionsAsync(context))
    {
      return;
    }

    var l = context.ServiceProvider.GetService<IStringLocalizer<...Resource>>();

    context.Groups.Add(new SettingComponentGroup("Settings", l["Settings"], typeof(CustomSettingComponent)));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

See an example usage: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/feature-management/src/Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.Blazor/Settings/FeatureSettingManagementComponentContributor.cs#L13-L28